# RPC: Child process that never die

Tags: c++, linux, fork, rpc, child-process

I am writing a program, based upon **C/C++ RPC** on linux OS (I am using Ubuntu 12.04), to create a peer-to-peer distributed chat. In order to complain with some project requests I need to do a **fork()**. I need to wait for the child process die before the parent process continue its flow: here the problem arises.

Each peer is composed by a client and a server(where problems arise).A general overview of the situation may be:

the generic "client1" sends a *ping* message to "server2" that answers with a *pong* message; at the same time "client2" sends a *ping* message to "server1" that answers with a *pong* message.

When I run the code the child does what it has to do but the parent never detect its child die.

Here I put a short piece of my very long server side code

```
int *chatline_0_svc(struct message *msg, struct svc_req *req)
```

{
        static int result = 1;

```
.......

switch(msg->msg_type)
{
    .......
    case ping:{ 
            int status;
            pid_t pidfork = fork();

            if(pidfork == 0)
            {
                //CHILD
                cout << "CHILD " << getpid() << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                waitpid(pidfork, &status, 0);
                cout << "PARENT" << endl;

                                    .......

            }
            break;
          }
                      .......
    }
cout << "PROCESS " << getpid() << endl;
return &result;
```

}

Peer1 output is:

> .......
>
> CHILD 7320
>
> PROCESS 7320
>
> ......

Peer2 output is:

> .......
>
> CHILD 7319
>
> PROCESS 7319
>
> ......

Has anybody got an idea about why child process seems always alive?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `exit` from the forked process like so:

```
if(pidfork == 0)
{
    //CHILD
    cout << "CHILD " << getpid() << endl;
    _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // or return
}
else
{
    waitpid(pidfork, &status, 0);
    cout << "PARENT" << endl;
}
```